# Generating dataset with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, bluebird

I'm currently trying to generate an array of pairs with asynchronous calls in javascript however I just cant seem to get it in the right order.

```
generateDataPoints: function (iterable, source, arg) {
  let pairs = []
  let prevTime = 0
  for (let index in iterable) {
    let event = iterable[index]
    getTime(event.valueOf()).then(function (time) {
      query(source[arg], event.valueOf()).then(function(val) {
        if (time !== prevTime) {
          prevTime = time
          pairs.push([time, val])
          console.log(pairs) // This works as expected but only happens after the program returns
        } else {
          Promise.resolve()
        }
      })
    })
  }
  return Promise.resolve(pairs)
}
```

The problem is that the "pairs.push.." command happens after I return. I am unable to figure out what exactly is going wrong and how I can synchronise this process. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so... uh, you certainly introduced a promise into your code, but, nothing you did with it would result in a promise being returned that doesn't resolve until the work is done.

Comment: @KevinB Hm, I tried wrapping the for loop in a new Promise, while returning "resolve(pairs)". That did not work either

Comment: You are looking for `Promise.all`. Create an array of promises, one for each individual result, with the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing synchronous code (like the for loop) with async code. Try something like this:

```
function generateDataPoints(iterable, source, arg) {
  let prevTime = 0
  [...iterable].reduce((promiseChain, event) => {
    let pairs;
    return promiseChain
      .then(p => {
        pairs = p;
        return Promise.all([
          getTime(event.valueOf()),
          query(source[arg], event.valueOf())
        ])
      })
      .then(([time, val]) => {
        if (time !== prevTime) {
          prevTime = time
          return pairs.concat([[time, val]]);
        } else {
          return pairs;
        }
      });
    })
  }, Promise.resolve([]));
}
```

This reduces `iterable` into a sequential Promise chain, which will eventually contain all the pairs.

If your environment allows for it, you could also convert your function with few changes to an *async* function:

```
generateDataPoints: async function (iterable, source, arg) {
  let pairs = []
  let prevTime = 0
  for (let index in iterable) {
    let event = iterable[index]
    const [time, val] = await Promise.all([
      getTime(event.valueOf()),
      query(source[arg], event.valueOf())
    ]);
    if (time !== prevTime) {
      prevTime = time
      pairs.push([time, val])
    }
  }
  return pairs;
}
```

**Edit**:

On closer look, it doesn't look like you need to sequentialize these Promises. You may be able to run them in parallel instead:

```
function generateDataPoints(iterable, source, arg) {
  Promise.all(
    [...iterable].map(event => Promise.all([
      getTime(event.valueOf()),
      query(source[arg], event.valueOf())
    ])
  ).then(pairs => {
    let prevTime = 0
    return pairs.filter(([time, val]) => {
      if (time !== prevTime) {
        prevTime = time;
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      } 
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You're also using Bluebird according to your tags. That means you have goodies like `Promise.map` which makes things even easier.

Comment: So I've currently implemented the third thing you've written and here is the problem. I have generateDataPoints called somewhere else, lets call the function x. X gets the list of pairs after the mapping is done, however the filtering process has not begun. Why is this?

Comment: Because `generateDataPoints()` returns a Promise, you need to await it. Do `.then(events => generateDataPoints(events, source, arg)).then(results => res.status(200).json(results))` instead.

Comment: Once again I get the same issue, I send the response before the filtering occurs. here is the full source code, I'm not sure what exactly I am doing wrong. My build system does inform me that my end point has created a promise handler but not returned from it https://pastebin.com/EHy9nnBX

Comment: Not sure if this is of any help, but everything seems to be working other than me returning from my promises. They are always undefined

Comment: You're missing the `return` when calling `Parity.generateDataPoints(events, contract, method, res)`. Also the `return` is missing in `generateDataPoints` should be returning the Promise.

Comment: Old post, but in essence the problem I was having was the node has a arbitrary limit for response times on requests (2 minutes). Processing large data sets cause my get request to prematurely return after two minutes, falsely leading me to believe the way I was structuring my promises was wrong.